# What is purpose use of 'ever' in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Very few people ever came that way. What is purpose use of 'ever'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example sentence, *ever* is used to make it clear that the statement covers *all of time* rather than a particular period.

For instance, contrast these two sentences:

> Very few people came that way *today*.
>   Very few people *ever* came that way.

The second sentence, with *ever*, makes it clear that it's not just a particular time period being discussed but *all* time periods.

---

You can use the same sentence without any qualification at all:

> Very few people came that way.

It would commonly be assumed that what's meant is the missing *ever*—but adding it in ensures that there is no room for misinterpretation.

---

Context is also important:

> "Was the south entrance busy today?"
>   "Very few people came that way."

Here, *today* is assumed in the answer.

> "Was the south entrance busy today?"
>   "Very few people ever come that way."

Here, the answer, a general statement, applies not just to today but all days.

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence *Very few people ever came that way* the purpose or function of *ever* is to act as an intensifier. *The Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar* (p220) defines *intensifier* as:

> An adverbial that scales another element upwards or downwards in
>   degrees of intensity.

*Collins Cobuild English  Grammar* (p216) has an  entry on *ever* that states:

> You can put *ever* after negative words in order to emphasize the
>   negative aspect of a statement.

Swan in *Practical English Usage* (190) says:

> We also use *ever*... with words that express a negative idea.

In the sentence *Very few people ever came that way* the words *very few* can be construed as a negative, and *ever* serves to intensify this.